# pushState on existing url, on refresh cause double url in history

Tags: api, refresh, double, history, pushstate

I've a problem. obviously.

First of all, sorry for my bad english. Then...

I'm using History.js for pushState and other function of History API in HTML5. But this is not the point.

example:

i've this url, generated with pushState, www.mysite.it/picture/2, that show a lightbox with the picture. When i load more images, with keypress or click, the pushState change the url to the next (or previous) url (ex. www.mysite.it/picture/3).

The problem is this: When i refresh the page, the site poin to the real page of www.mysite.it/picture/2, and it's ok, but, when i click on the BACK button i've in history the same url (www.mysite.it/picture/2) for the second time. I think that this happen because when i refresh i create e new history row.

...i dont know how to solve this problem. Please, help :)

**Problem Solved**

i've writing the pushState function outside of the if that determinate what key the user have pressed. So, when cntrl+r was pressed for refresh, another row  was added to the history. xD